# Syntax for using variable names for error checking

Tags: angular, input, error-handling

I am building dynamic input fields with a mandatory check inside `ngFor`. I have built names using `field{{idxVar}}` where `idxVar` is index but how do I use this for checking error

```
<span [ngClass]="{'active' : field{{idxVar}}.errors}">*Mandatory</span>
<input type="text" [required]="itmVar.is_required ? 'required' : null" name="field{{idxVar}}" [(ngModel)]="user.customFields[idxVar]"
            #field{{idxVar}}="ngModel">
```

In above, I know this is not the right method which gives error but want to know the right syntax for this

```
'active' : field{{idxVar}}.errors
```

Comment: Take a look at this article. It may help you refresh your mind. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt847185.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For NgModel inside *ngFor, you can use unique template reference variable. Each input field is associated to the corresponding template reference, array index is not required.

```
<div *ngFor="let idxVar of valueArray">
  <span [ngClass]="{'active' : field.errors}">*Mandatory</span>
    <input type="text" name="field{{idxVar}}" [ngModel]="valueArray[idxVar]"
                #field="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="callback(field)">
    <div>{{ field.control.errors | json }}</div>
</div>
```

Here is the stackblitz code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4skhz

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you are trying to do but it seems what would work best for you would be to create an object `fields` with keys of numbers, corresponding to the indices you want to check on.

In your controller, have a `fields` object.

Then your template code would become something like

```
<span [ngClass]="{'active' : field[idxVar].errors}">*Mandatory</span>
<input type="text" [required]="itmVar.is_required ? 'required' : null" name="field[idxVar]" [(ngModel)]="user.customFields[idxVar]">
```

Here's a quick example in Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p4zemy

If this answer satisfies your needs, please be sure to mark it as accepted.